# Proving that every integer greater than or equal to $2$ can be uniquely factored into primes

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, induction, proof-explanation

I need to prove:

> Every integer $n$, $n \ge 2$, can be factored uniquely into primes.  (By "unique," we mean unique up to the order in which the primes are listed.)

I assume I need to use induction, but I'm unsure of how to prove the $n+1$ case.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [unique factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) is easily researched online (or in your text).

Answer (score 2):

Assume the statement is false.  Because the positive integers are well ordered, there is a smallest $n$ that cannot be uniquely factored into primes.  Then $n$ cannot itself be prime or $n=n$ is the unique prime factorization of $n$.  Thus, $\exists a, b \lt n$ such that $n=ab$.

But $n$ is the smallest number that cannot be uniquely factored into primes, so $a, b \lt n \Rightarrow a \text{ and } b$ can be factored into primes (and indeed, we can do so uniquely).  That demonstrates that $n$ is a product of primes, so $n=pm$ for some prime $p, m =n/p \lt  n$.  Because $n/p$ can be factored into primes uniquely, it follows that the prime factorization of $n$ is likewise unique, contradicting our original assumption that $n$ cannot be uniquely factored into primes.